# Is it more accessible to use a <button> or <a> to open/close a modal?

Tags: html, button, modal-dialog, anchor, accessibility

From my understanding, buttons are used to carry out functions and links are used to navigate the user to a different page. But what is best practice in terms of opening and closing a modal?

```
<a id="testModal" href="#">Open Modal</a>
```

or

```
<button id="testModal">Open Modal</button>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`<button>`

Change the `<a href="#">` to a `<button>` and put your event handler on it.

Some more context on which elements belongs where....

**Does the Control Take Me to Another Page? Use an Anchor**

If, when clicked, tapped, or activated by keyboard or voice (or insert novel interaction method here), the user is whisked to another URL (including an anchor on the same page), then use `<a href="[URL]">`. Make sure you use the `href` attribute and that it has a real URL, not a “#” (otherwise you’re probably relying on JavaScript, which is not at all necessary for a hyperlink). If an `href` points to just a “#”, then you’re probably doing it wrong. If it points to a named anchor as part of your progressive enhancement efforts, then that’s totally valid.

**Does the Control Change Something on the Current Page? Use a Button**

If, when activated, the user is not moved from the page (or to an anchor within the page), but instead is presented with a new view (message boxes, changes in layout, etc.), then use a `<button>`. While you could use an`<input type="button">`, it’s more likely you’ll get into conflicts with pre-existing styles and subsequent developers (like me).

**Does the Control Submit Form Fields? Use a Submit**

If, when activated, information the user has entered (either by manually typing or by choosing items on the screen) is being sent back to the server, then use an `<input type="submit">`. This has better live within a `<form>`. If you need more styling control or have to embed more than just a simple text string, use a `<button type="submit">` instead.

**Keyboard Considerations**

Think of keyboard users for a moment. A hyperlink can be fired by pressing the enter key. But a true button can be fired by pressing the enter key or the space bar. When a hyperlink has focus and the user presses the space bar, the page will scroll one screenful. If there isn’t more to scroll then the user just experiences nothing. Given a set of interface elements that look the same, if some work with a space bar and some don’t, you can’t expect users to have much confidence in how the page behaves.

I think it’s also worth mentioning that events triggered by a space bar only fire when the key is released, whereas using the Enter key will fire the event as soon as you press the key down (prior to releasing it).

Comment: if only JS is handling the form submission (ajax or otherwise changes serialization format), what is the benefit of using a submit? (you'll have to be careful to invoke `preventDefault()` to prevent an http submission back to itself).

Comment: @cowbert, the advantage of using one control over another, regardless of use of script, is that each control exposes itself differently to assistive technology and is operated differently. See the _Keyboard Considerations_ section of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are two possible cases.

1. Your content is only visually hidden in page or visible in page (can be read by screen readers) and can be hash linked, then an anchor tag might be appropriate (this case is not so common, eg: use case is if you are highlighting a paragraph or image on the page as a modal).
2. In almost all other cases, your modal is loaded on the same page and is in no way navigated using a url link (except through ajax for accessing data possibly, which doesn't count). Hence it is a custom functionality and a button is the appropriate choice.

Answer (score 3):

Sort of by definition, a dialog is something that will pop up over the current window.  You're not really leaving the window, it's just temporarily unavailable.  Once you're done with the dialog, you typically go back to the window.  So in that respect, you don't want to use a link because you're not going to another page.  You're doing some action on the current page.  Use a button.

When using a screen reader, I will often bring up the list of links (Ins+F7 in JAWS) to see what pages I can link to.  I'll also bring up a list of buttons (Ctrl+Ins+B) to see what actions are available on the page.  I would expect the action to bring up a modal dialog to be in my button list.